# One php recordset instead of 7 ? Extra filtering during presentation

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table about a program guide with 4 columns: idguide, idday, starthour, program. 
I would like to present it on the screen per day.
Must i call 7 times its recordset, like this
SELECT * FROM tblguide WHERE idday = 1 ORDER BY `start` ASC

This works but causes bigger workload; is there another solution where i only have one recordset
and filter the idday during the presentation ?
SELECT * FROM tblguide ORDER BY `start` ASC

I don't know which solution ? Arrays i'm not so familiar with.
Thanks for helping me !

Answer (score 0):

Don't you mean

```
SELECT * FROM tblguide ORDER BY idday, start;
```

and do the rest while retrieving?

**Edit:**

```
$oldday = null;
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($whatever)) {
    if($oldday!=$r['idday']) {
        // It's a new day!
        $oldday = $r['idday'];
    }
    // whatever
}
```